# Multilingual ComboBox Bound to Enum Descriptions In DataTemplate Using DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, multilingual, datatemplateselector

I'm working on something where the individual parts have been well discussed  but I'm having trouble putting them all together.  We have an app that has lots of plugins that require different input parameters which I'm trying to make multi-lingual.  I've been working on a dynamic GUI that inspects the plugin to create an array of input parameters and uses a DataTemplateSelector to pick the correct control based on the parameter's type.  For enumerators we're trying to bind a localized display name to a combobox.  There's lots of threads on StackOverflow on how to do enum/combobox binding but none that I could find that are multi-lingual and dynamic (datatemplate or other).

Brian Lagunas has a great blog post that almost gets us there: http://brianlagunas.com/localize-enum-descriptions-in-wpf.  However, he statically binds the enum in the XAML.  We have hundreds of enums and are creating new ones all the time.  So I'm trying to get my head around how to best achieve something more dynamic.  Somewhere along the line I need to use reflection to figure out the enumerator's type and bind it to the combobox but I can't quite figure out where, when, or how.

I've uploaded an extended example here: https://github.com/bryandam/Combo_Enum_MultiLingual.  I'll try and include the relevant pieces here but it's hard to condense it down.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Object> InputParameterList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        //Create an example input object.
        InputParameter bitlocker_drive = new InputParameter();
        bitlocker_drive.Name = "BitLocker Enabled";
        bitlocker_drive.Type = typeof(String);
        InputParameterList.Add(bitlocker_drive);

        InputParameter bitlocker_status = new InputParameter();
        bitlocker_status.Name = "Status";
        bitlocker_status.Type = typeof(Status);
        InputParameterList.Add(bitlocker_status);

        InputParameter bitlocker_foo = new InputParameter();
        bitlocker_foo.Name = "Foo";
        bitlocker_foo.Type = typeof(Foo);
        InputParameterList.Add(bitlocker_foo);
    }
}
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingEnums.MainWindow"
  ....
<Window.Resources>        
    ...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBox">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:Status}}}" Grid.Column="1"/>                
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    ...
    <local:InputParameterTemplateSelector x:Key="InputDataTemplateSelector" Checkbox="{StaticResource Checkbox}" ComboBox="{StaticResource ComboBox}" DatePicker="{StaticResource DatePicker}" TextBox="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="InputParameters" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding InputParameterList}"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource InputDataTemplateSelector}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Here's two example enums I'm testing with:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum Status
{        
    [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.EnumResources.Good), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.EnumResources))]
    Good,
    [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.EnumResources.Better), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.EnumResources))]
    Better,
    Best
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionTypeConverter))]
public enum Foo
{
    [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.EnumResources.Foo), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.EnumResources))]
    Foo,
    [Display(Name = nameof(Resources.EnumResources.Bar), ResourceType = typeof(Resources.EnumResources))]
    Bar
}
```

Here's the enum type convertor:

```
    public class EnumDescriptionTypeConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public EnumDescriptionTypeConverter(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {}

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
                if (fi != null)
                {
                    //Reflect into the value's type to get the display attributes.
                    FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
                    DisplayAttribute displayAttribute = fieldInfo?
                                                    .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                                    .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
                                                    .SingleOrDefault();
                    if (displayAttribute == null)
                    {
                        return value.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Look up the localized string.
                        ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(displayAttribute.ResourceType);                            
                        string name = resourceManager.GetString(displayAttribute.Name);
                        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ? displayAttribute.Name : name;
                    }
                }
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
```

Here's the Enum Binding Source Markup Extension:

```
public class EnumBindingSourceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    ...

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (null == this._enumType)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The EnumType must be specified.");

        Type actualEnumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(this._enumType) ?? this._enumType;
        Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(actualEnumType);

        if (actualEnumType == this._enumType)
            return enumValues;

        Array tempArray = Array.CreateInstance(actualEnumType, enumValues.Length + 1);
        enumValues.CopyTo(tempArray, 1);
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```

Again, my goal is to figure out how to avoid statically binding to a single enum type (like in the XAML below) and instead bind it based on whatever type the input parameter might be:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:Status}}}" Grid.Column="1"/
```

I've played around with doing it in the Window code-behind, the data template selector, and even a custom control without too much success.  My first 'real' WPF app so I'm admittedly a tad out of my league putting all of this together versus their individual parts.

[Here's the example running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4VdV.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not really clear what you're asking here, you say that you're trying to avoid binding to the enum....why? Ultimately you're going to be binding to that enum one way or another, even if you don't do it through the WPF binding mechanism. There are many, many ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but you'll need to be a bit more specific as to the reasons behind your requirements (which for all we know could very well not be a problem at all).

Comment: Fair point, edited that last bit for clarity and added a second enum to example.  I want to bind, I just need to do so dynamically.  The solution so far only works if I statically bind the combobox to a single enumerator type directly in XAML.  I'm trying to extend it so that it will support any enumerator we throw at it.  I suspect that means binding it in code behind somewhere but that gets tricky (for me) because it's in a data template so first you have to figure out what control your binding to. Then, there theoretically could be multiple enums as part of the input parameter array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, took a few days of hacking around but I **finally** figured this out.  In the MarkupExtensions's ProvideValue call you can get the IProvideValueTarget service to get the target.  This allows you to do two things.  First, you can check to see if the target is null and thus bypass the initial startup call and delay the binding until the datatemplate is applied.  Second, once the template is applied you can get the datacontext of the object allowing you to reflect into it and thus eliminate the need to declare it at design time (my ultimate goal).

Here's my MarkupExtension class' ProvideValue function:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //Get the target control
    var pvt = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
    if (pvt == null) { return null; }
    var target = pvt.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;

    //If null then return the class to bind at runtime.
    if (target == null) { return this; }

    if (target.DataContext.GetType().IsEnum)
    {
            Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(target.DataContext.GetType());
            return enumValues;                
    }
    return null;
}
```

The end result being that I can specify the combobox itemsource without specifying a single, static type:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{local:EnumBindingSource}"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible "solution" to this is to just drop the use of enums for localization altogether. This is what I do, it allows myself and other devs on the project to insert plain English into our XAML like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate 'Scanning Passport'}" />
```

I wrote a little utility to scan our XAML files and pull all instances of these into an Excel spreadsheet which gets sent to the translators, a second utility takes the translations we get back and packs them into XML files (one per language). These files are basically dictionaries, where the English text in the XAML is used as the key to look up the translation in the currently selected language:

```
<Translation key="Scan Passport" text="扫描护照" />
```

This has a number of benefits:

- Developers still write their XAML in a common language (English in my case).
- You don't have to rebuild every project in your solution every time you add new text to your front end.
- If you add new text that hasn't been translated yet then
  the `Translate' extension just falls back to the English
  translation.
- The XML files are stored locally, so the client is free to change localization text at will (including English).
- You have full control over which fields in your GUI go through translation and which ones don't.

And of course if you change the translation at run-time then the controls that are being translated all update themselves and switch over to the new language immediately.

The key to this system, obviously, is writing that 'Translate' custom markup extension, fortunately someone's already done that for you:

https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

Comment: I'll give it some thought.  The enums is just the more difficult part of the overall problem we're working on.  There's a server/client component here that was previously exchanging purely string types which made it tough to do a good GUI based on reflection.  We are planning for multiple GUIs and constant new streams of plugins so we're trying to move to real object types so we can reflect into them and make smarter GUI choices (ex. combo for enum, checkbox for bool, ect.)
Thanks for thinking through this with me Mark.